# Loop that group the same values nad put them in new csv. file

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create script that will group the same values from column and create new csv. file for each unique value.
"Order no." is the value that i want to use to group data.
May i please you for an advice how to create loop for that?
Thanks

```
Public count As Integer

Sub Makro()
Dim RowSource, RowTarget, Line, counter, lastrow  As Integer

RowMaxSrc = Sheets("P4").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Import_View").Range("A1:Z999").Clear
With Sheets("P4")
RowTarget = 1
Line = 1000
counter = 0
For RowSource = 2 To RowMaxSrc

If Sheets("P4").Cells(RowSource, 16) = "Import" Then
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 1).Value = "I"
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 2).Value = Line
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 3).Value = "MA"
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 4).Value = .Cells(RowSource, 2) 'Order no.'
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 5).Value = 10
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 6).Value = .Cells(RowSource, 13) 'Article'
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 7).Value = .Cells(RowSource, 15) 'Qty'
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 8).Value = .Cells(RowSource, 14) 'LOT'
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 9).Value = "SNAP" 'stock
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 10).Value = Format(.Cells(RowSource, 18), "mmddyyyy")


Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 11).Value = .Cells(RowSource, 16) 'Import Flag'
Sheets("Import_View").Cells(RowTarget, 12).Value = .Cells(RowSource, 1) 'LP'
'Sheets("P4").Cells(RowSource, 16).Value = "Imported"


RowTarget = RowTarget + 1
counter = counter + 1
count = count + 1


Else

End If
Next

MsgBox ("Imported products: " + CStr(counter))
'MsgBox ("Imported products overall: " + CStr(count))

lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:L" & lastrow).Sort key2:=Range("D1:D" & lastrow), key1:=Range("J1:J" & lastrow), order1:=xlAscending, order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo


If Sheets("Import_View").Range("A1").Cells.Value = "I" Then
 fldr = ThisWorkbook.Path
    x = fldr + "\Import\" + "Import" + Format(Time, "hh-mm-ss") + ".csv"
    
    
    Sheets("Import_View").Select
    Sheets("Import_View").Copy
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs x, xlCSV, Local:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
    
   
    Else
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "group the same values"?  And what part of your code isn't working?

Comment: one way to solve is first sort it out using order no then group the values .